# Create polygons from points

Tags: line, geometry-conversion, points-to-line

I have a points dataset, which contains what are essentially vertices of polygons. They represent a number of separate, discrete polygons, and there is a field delineating these by name. Using this field, upon executing a 'Points to Line' tool, I am able to specify which points belong to which polygon. However, I can't specify which points are to be drawn in which order. The only other field is FID, and the points are not in the correct order such that it creates the proper polygon shape. For example, a polygon that is supposed to be a circle comes out with lines drawn between vertices on opposite sides, rather than the circle it is supposed to be. Is there a way to get the polygons to generate properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this Concave Hull tool, if you are missing a field defining the vertice order.. https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/06/11/bruce-harolds-concave-hull-estimator-tool-enhanced

Answer (score 0):

I assume you input the polygon name that the points belong to in the Line Field. The field located underneath that, the Sort Field, is the field that determines the order in which they are drawn.